# Linear Algebra Null space and subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Are these both true?
For two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$, $\text{Nul}(AB)$ is a subspace of $\text{Nul}(A)$.
For two $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$, $\text{Nul}(AB)$ is a subspace of $\text{Nul}(B)$.

I can't seem to find a coutnerexample

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both false. For the first one, take $B = 0$ and $A \neq 0$. Then $\mathrm{Nul}(AB) = \mathbb R^n$ but not $\mathrm{Nul}(A)$. For the second one, take $A = 0$ and $B \neq 0$ ; similar ideas apply.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

Neither is true.  $Bx=0 \Rightarrow ABx=0$, so Nul B is a subspace of Nul AB.